# Allow URLs with Dashes on azure websites

Tags: codeigniter, url, iis, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to make an SEO friendly link for a downloads page 
using codeigniter hosted on Azure Websites, now this is working:

```
www.example.com/downloads/viewfile/34
```

now when i generated this link :

```
www.example.com/downloads/viewfile/my-nice-file-name-34
```

the Url rewrite works great locally on a WAMP server, but when deployed to the remote (Azure Webites IIS ?) it gives the error:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I believe that the cause is: dash symbols are not allowed on IIS but is there a way arround ?

Comment: PHP/Codeigniter on IIS - yuck.

Comment: how do you generate the 2nd link with dashes ? with .htaccess or with routes.php ?

Comment: just using the helper function url_title()

Answer (score 2):

After all, i found out that its not the dash symbols that are causing the problem, but the words in the url itself

like yesterday i had `www.example.com/downloads/viewfile/example-file-34`
to some reason, having your domain-name in the url segments makes that error apear, so i simply replaced "mydomain" into nothing before generating the Url segment

```
$fileName = str_replace('mydomain','',$fileName);
return url_title($fileName.$fileId);
```

Now the same link above is `www.example.com/downloads/viewfile/file-34` and its working fine.

i also noticed that same behavior is experienced when using some words like : ajax, json.

I hope this would be helful to somone.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.php file

Find

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Replace with

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

You may need to look also into

URI Routing Codeigniter 3

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Codeigniter 2 URI Routing

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html